# Appending a pattern to the default diff header pattern (diff.cpp.xfuncname)

Tags: git

I want to extend (but not replace) the default diff header pattern for C files.  According to this [post](http://lists-archives.com/git/873479-appending-a-pattern-to-the-default-diff-cpp-xfuncname.html):

> you are stuck with extracting the builtin value (which
>   annoyingly, you cannot even get without looking at the source code!),
>   and repeating it in your config file.

However, the builtin value looks like this in C:

```c
PATTERNS("cpp",
     /* Jump targets or access declarations */
     "!^[ \t]*[A-Za-z_][A-Za-z_0-9]*:[[:space:]]*($|/[/*])\n"
     /* functions/methods, variables, and compounds at top level */
     "^((::[[:space:]]*)?[A-Za-z_].*)$",
     /* -- */
     "[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*"
     "|[-+0-9.e]+[fFlL]?|0[xXbB]?[0-9a-fA-F]+[lLuU]*"
     "|[-+*/<>%&^|=!]=|--|\\+\\+|<<=?|>>=?|&&|\\|\\||::|->\\*?|\\.\\*"),
```

Which I'm not sure how to render in a `.gitconfig` file.

I tried

```
xfuncname = "(!^[ \t]*[A-Za-z_][A-Za-z_0-9]*:[[:space:]]*($|/[/*])\n)|(^((::[[:space:]]*)?[A-Za-z_].*)$\n)|([a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*)|([-+0-9.e]+[fFlL]?|0[xXbB]?[0-9a-fA-F]+[lLuU]*)|([-+*/<>%&^|=!]=|--|\\+\\+|<<=?|>>=?|&&|\\|\\||::|->\\*?|\\.\\*)"
```

which gives me `fatal: Invalid regexp to look for hunk header: (!^[     ]*[A-Za-z_][A-Za-z_0-9]*:[[:space:]]*($|/[/*])` when running `git diff`.

Doubling backslashes also does not work:

```
xfuncname = "(!^[ \\t]*[A-Za-z_][A-Za-z_0-9]*:[[:space:]]*($|/[/*])\\n)|(^((::[[:space:]]*)?[A-Za-z_].*)$\\n)|([a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*)|([-+0-9.e]+[fFlL]?|0[xXbB]?[0-9a-fA-F]+[lLuU]*)|([-+*/<>%&^|=!]=|--|\\\\+\\\\+|<<=?|>>=?|&&|\\\\|\\\\||::|->\\\\*?|\\\\.\\\\*)"
```

No error, but the diff headers are blank, i.e., it fails to match anything.

Answer (score 0):

Try at least to double the `\`.
[gitattributes](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes#_defining_a_custom_hunk_header) does mention:

```
[diff "tex"]
    xfuncname = "^(\\\\(sub)*section\\{.*)$"
```

> Note. **A single level of backslashes are eaten by the configuration file parser, so you would need to double the backslashes**; the pattern above picks a line that begins with a backslash, and zero or more occurrences of sub followed by section followed by open brace, to the end of line.

Comment: Nope, doesn't work (see my edit). I thought C string literals would already have the same doubling anyway.

Comment: @npostavs At this point, I would still double the `\`, but with a simpler regex in order to if that works, then build back in the all regex to see what part is actually problematic.

Comment: Hmm, just realized that the PATTERNS macro takes both diff header and word_regex patterns; I overlooked that comma.